# link_to method post still shows as get in browser bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

Doing a post link

```
<%= link_to "Check it", all_integrations_path({q: {location_cont_any: us_states}, sort_by: "twitter_followers"}), method: :post %>
```

While in this railscasts when he did the post method it led the url to be `/produces/search`
http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack

Mine ends up looking like a mess like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/integrations/all?q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Alabama&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Alaska&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Arizona&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Arkansas&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=California&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Colorado&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Connecticut&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Delaware&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=District+of+Columbia&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Florida&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Georgia&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Hawaii&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Idaho&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Illinois&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Indiana&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Iowa&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Kansas&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Kentucky&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Louisiana&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Maine&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Maryland&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Massachusetts&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Michigan&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Minnesota&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Mississippi&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Missouri&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Montana&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Nebraska&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Nevada&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=New+Hampshire&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=New+Jersey&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=New+Mexico&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=New+York&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=North+Carolina&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=North+Dakota&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Ohio&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Oklahoma&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Oregon&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Pennsylvania&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Rhode+Island&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=South+Carolina&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=South+Dakota&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Tennessee&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Texas&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Utah&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Vermont&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Virginia&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Washington&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=West+Virginia&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=Wisconsin&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5%20D=Wyoming&sort_by=twitter_followers
```

While i'd like it to be `/integrations/all`

Thanks!

Comment: The railscast is using a form with post, a regular link doesn't work that way.

Comment: Like @Iceman said, is there a reason you need to use `link_to` instead of a Rails form? You could accomplish the former using some Javascript but it's certainly not the ideal solution.